# Visual Studio 2010 Express. Write to the output window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm new to Visual Studio and Windows Phone 7 developping. I did activate the redirect all output text option, but neith Debug.Writeline() or Console.WriteLine() are working...

How can I log infos ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Took me a while to find this one as well

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Yay!");`

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine` *should* come out to the "output" window in visual studio when debugging.  because the output window can show outputs from all kinds of places (build, debug, etc) make sure the output window is set to "show output from" debug.

Comment: I did check the "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" option, and I shouldn't have. Both your answers are working now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: There seems to be some limit of text that is output.. i am trying to print a large amount of text and its only showing a little bit. any way to show it all?