# Visual Studio Express 2013: Program output in unit tests (console, debug etc.)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, output, visual-studio-express

I'm really banging my head against the wall here. Is it so hard to get program output in Visual Studio (Express 2013)? When writing code, I find it absolutely essential to be able to print out the values of variables, operations etc. while working and troubleshooting.

In Java and Eclipse, the System.out.println() allways works, printing to the IDE console. When writing C programs I allways use the console, so echoing anything is no problem. However, in VS Express 2013 I can't seem to get any output.

Can the problem be related to the fact that I'm writing unit tests, and not "normal" executable programs? If so, is there some way to get VS to show program output in unit test classes? I've tried using debug, but that doesn't show anything either. Thinking that there's a config problem, I've looked for solutions to debug messages not showing, but none of the options I've found (in here or other places) seem to help.

Or, of course - if there's another commonly used method for checking program values, output etc. while writing code in VS/C#, I'd like to hear about it :-)

Anyone got any ideas? And please, if the question is too unclear or something, tell me and I'll fix it.

NB: I'm using unit test classes for functional testing, in case someone wants to point out what I should and and shouldn't do with unit tests.

EDIT 1: I forgot to mention that I'm not able to run the code with "Start: Debug". If I try, I get this error: "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly." (The unit test project uses classes in another project, which i a class library project.) This is, of course, because I have no executable project in the solution. The way I run it is to run the selected test, from the Test Explorer.

EDIT 2: Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WordpressAutomation;

namespace WordpressTests
{

    [TestClass]
    public class LoginTests : WordpressTest {

        [TestMethod]
        public void AdminUserCanLogIn() {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something...");
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Something...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really like answering my own question, since it seems kind of "dishonest". However, it's been quiet for a while, and I don't think there are other answers.

The most practical solution is to create another project, for example a console project, where you create all the output. It might not communicate directly with the unit tests, but since the test framework I'm developing in this specific example consists of functional tests speaking to class libraries, it's possible to use a separate project in the solution.

So, to summarize, the solution consists of:
- A unit test project, with the actual tests
- A class library project with the framework logic
- A console project for testing classes in the class library, or non-unit test classes in the unit test project.

Comment: Don't worry about answering your own question. Stack Overflow encourages answering your own questions if you figure out an adequate question. You don't just ask questions for yourself, you also ask them for future visitors who might have the same question.

Comment: Yes, on occasion, I've asked a question and answered it immediately (via the "share your knowledge, Q&A style checkbox), simply because I was sure I would have the problem again, and I wanted a google search to find it.

Answer (score 34):

The TestExplorer of Visual Studio has a separate output window. It does not write to the default Output of Visual Studio (I do not know if it is configurable)

You have to select the Test you want to see the output in the TestExplorer. If Test has some Output you should see a Hyperlink "Output". Clicking that will open a new tab displaying the output of the Test.

[image]

The displayed messages are all written by `Console.WriteLine`.

I´m using Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I´m not sure if the Express version works diffrent.

Comment: Hm. Yes. I see. That's probably the closest I can get to output from unit tests? I think probably creating a console project to live parallell with the test project is the way to go.

Comment: After doing this and that for a long time, I've come to the conclusion that this is a very practical solution.

Comment: hmm this doesn't seem to be working in vs2015 enterprise though

Comment: Large test outputs crash VS 2013

Comment: This works in vs2015 but if you're using a runsettings file, make sure CaptureTraceOutput in MSTest settings is set to true.

Answer (score 6):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Yay!");
```

If you configure your Output window to display debug data, it shows in there.

Source: [Visual Studio 2010 Express. Write to the output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108381/visual-studio-2010-express-write-to-the-output-window) (It is for VS 2010, but it should also apply to 2013 since this is a framework option, not an IDE option).

Comment: But how do I configure the output window? In my output window, I have selected "Show output from: Debug". But it seems that, since this is a unit test, I cannot run it in normal debug mode.

Comment: As far as I know, debug.writeline should also work on a project in release configuration. I'm going to test this right now.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)` will work, when the "DEBUG" symbol is defined. You could use `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(...)`.

Comment: I cannot execute directly, in Debug nor Release mode. The way I run the class(es) is from the Test Explorer. I've tried Trace.Writeline() too, but none of these gives any output when I'm running the unit test. That's why I was thinking maybe the problem/challenge is that the project is a unit test project...

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you should use ***log***, not console output for situation like this. You can config log to output to a file, or even output to a window you specified. I believe you can use log for situation without console, and you can configure you log that only warning or error come out in production, and debug information can be displayed during your debug session.

I use [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), any good log software can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You should leverage a logging framework to do this kind of thing.  From the logging framework, you can choose to log to the console, or to a flat file, or many other data sinks, or you can tell the framework to ignore the input.  Good logging frameworks are extremely configurable.

In .NET land, the community favorite seems to be NLog, http://nlog-project.org/ .  The "Getting Started" link will get you going.

Comment: I found an easier solution long ago: Just use Console.Write, and check the test output.

Comment: Sure, you can use Console.WriteLine.  It's simple and fast.

In the future, if you want output from classes you're going to publish, and if you don't want your output being displayed to the console when somebody writes your program, you'll need a different way.  Since this output is useful at test time, you might find it useful when the code is in another environment.  With Console.WriteLine, your options are pretty limited.

By using a logging framework, you can limit visibility of this output, and you can see this output in formats of your choosing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about VS2013, but in VS2008, if you double-click on the test result  summary (after it completes, either pass or fail), it will open a window with "Common Results", "Error Message", etc followed at the end by "Standard Console Output".  It basically does a nice job of capturing the console output for each test individually.  The only drawback is that it doesn't show the output in real time. It will only show it on completion.

Answer (score 0):

> A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started
>   directly

One doesn't run or debug a unit test project. One initiates a test session by either selecting 1 or more tests in `Test Explorer` window. Or on a unit test method by right clicking and selecting `Run Tests` or `Debug Tests`.

Use `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine` to output informational messages as needed and look for them in the `Output` link in the unit test results.

Comment: Not sure why you're answering a two year old question which I've answered myself two years ago.

Comment: @FrankH I answered because I landed on this page in researching an issue and directly answered to the fact that one doesn't hit `F5` to debug a unit test. Your answer didn't mention that fact. Others who land on this who are learning may not understand that operation in Visual Studio.